# R setting default value for missing factor value

Tags: r

I'm often working with `formula` objects and found it's very convenient reshaping discrete variables to factors. Assume the following example:

```
library(caret); library(data.table); data("iris"); iris <- as.data.table(iris)
dummy <- dummyVars(~ -1 + factor(Species, 
                                 levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
                                 ), data = iris)
predict(dummy, newdata = iris[1,])
```

Which returns a proper frame as expected.

**My question:**

In case a new undefined level of `Species` is given, the factor returns `NA`, while additionally messing up the final output:

```
predict(dummy, newdata = iris[1,][, Species:= "something_undefined"])
```

However, in some cases it is useful replacing new labels as a default value, i.e., typical/median label instead of `NA`. One possible way I could think of is writing a custom `custom.na.impute` function to deal with such values and using it for default `na.action`, i.e.,

```
predict(dummy, newdata = iris[1,][, Species:= "something_undefined"], 
        na.action = custom.na.impute)
```

However, if I understand correctly, here I'd have to manually write rules for all different factors and update it with inclusion of new factors. **Instead I'm looking for something like this**:

```
factor(Species, levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
                na.value = "setosa")
```

That is, to be able to define a default/missing value for any `factor` and specify it directly in the formula object, without having to mess around with custom `na.actions`.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commenting on my own question, since I wasn't able to find a cleaner/realized solution in an existing package. But it may be useful for someone.

In either case, a  better solution is still welcome!

The solution was to modify the existing `factor` function in the following manner:

```
factor2 <- function (x = character(), levels, labels = levels, exclude = NA, 
          ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA, default = NA) 
{
  # --- Added rows
  if(!is.na(default)){
    levels <- unique(c(levels, default))
  }
  # ---

  if (is.null(x)) 
    x <- character()
  nx <- names(x)
  if (missing(levels)) {
    y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
    ind <- sort.list(y)
    y <- as.character(y)
    levels <- unique(y[ind])
  }
  force(ordered)
  exclude <- as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
  x <- as.character(x)
  levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]

  # --- Modified rows
  f <- match(x, levels, nomatch = which(levels == default)[1])
  # ---

  if (!is.null(nx)) 
    names(f) <- nx
  nl <- length(labels)
  nL <- length(levels)
  if (!any(nl == c(1L, nL))) 
    stop(gettextf("invalid 'labels'; length %d should be 1 or %d", 
                  nl, nL), domain = NA)
  levels(f) <- if (nl == nL) 
    as.character(labels)
  else paste0(labels, seq_along(levels))
  class(f) <- c(if (ordered) "ordered", "factor")
  f
}
```

Now the `default` value is either added as a new level, or the matching is corrected when the new value is not it `levels`.

Now the prediction is working as intended:

```
dummy <- dummyVars(~ -1 + factor2(Species, 
                                 levels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
                                 default = "versicolor"
), data = iris)
```

Prediction returns the proper default level without further modifications of any code:

```
predict(dummy, newdata = iris[1,][, Species:= "something_undefined"])
```

Note: instead of `factor2`, `assignInNamespace('factor', factor2, 'base')` should work too, though it is more intrusive.